# An attempt to switch to a doublescan X11 modeline fails with "Configure crtc 0 failed"

Tags: display, resolution, xorg, xrandr, modeline

I have a modern `1920x1200` LED display, capable of up to 96 kHz `HorizSync`, up to 76 Hz `VertRefresh`, and up to 205 MHz pixel clock.

Apart from its native resolution, the display can also run in `1600x1200` (4:3) resolution at 75 Hz:

```
  1600x1200 (0xa1) 202.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  93.75KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  75.00Hz
```

Now, I'm trying to switch it to a `800x600` doublescan mode equivalent to the above `1600x1200` mode (at 75 Hz, too; all modelines taken from [here](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Modeline_Database)):

```bsh
xrandr --newmode "800x600d" 101.25 800 832 928 1080 600 600 602 625 DoubleScan +HSync +VSync
xrandr --addmode DP1 800x600d
```

The resulting video mode gets added successfully and is clearly visible in the output of `xrandr`:

```
  800x600d (0x1f7) 101.250MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  93.75KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
```

But once I attempt to switch to the new mode, I immediately receive an error:

```bsh
# Mode by name
$ xrandr --output DP1 --mode 800x600d
xrandr: cannot find mode 800x600d

# Mode by id
$ xrandr --output DP1 --mode 0x1f7
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Are modern graphics cards no longer able to run in a doublescan mode?
Or should I blame my display?

Comment: This question already has an answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611581

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't comment without reputation, but here is a similar thread:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/136139/xrandr-configure-crtc-0-failed-when-trying-to-change-resolution-on-external-m

I am not sure why would you want to use doublescan, at a lower resolution deliberatly. In any case, you might want to try `arandr` and see if you can set it up that way. xrandr might be a little tricky to get right in these cases.

Comment: Thank you.

My question was specifically about doublescan `ModeLine`'s, since `Configure crtc 0 failed` is a rather generic error message which may be caused by a number of reasons.

I've already received an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611626/94327), so will most probably close this question as a duplicate.